# Orchard content permission dashboard, hide content menu to user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, admin, orchardcms, dashboard, orchardcms-1.6

I'm creating a custom module.

In my scenario I have an user that needs to see the dashboard and in it just my module admin menu.

I have granted appropriate permission to a new user and a new role I created for this specific purpose.

My module is ok but the new user sees the Content menu as well.

The user has just my role enabled.

No permissions on Content are checked, specifically "View All Content" is NOT checked on my role but it is checked on Authenticated role.

If I remove "View All content" from Authenticated users the users that logs in cannot see content in public part of site and the Content menu is still visible on dashboard...

So far it seems to me a bug but before filing it as BUG I would see if there is a workaround.

The question is:
"How can I hide completely the content menu to an user that has a specific role set?"

My orchard version is Orchard v.1.7.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the dashboard does not support hiding particular items based on permissions. The dashboard is meant to be used by administrators only and regular users should not be allowed to access it.

If you are trying to expose settings for non-admin users, then I would suggest moving your settings form outside of the dashboard to a regular view. Then you can display it only for particular users based on permissions or any other criteria.

Comment: Well actually my module is an admin module and some mode advanced  users need some admin functions (like users and roles) and other settings... the point is that they do not need the content menu and I find confusing have it there: they do not need to add content to site and I have an extra menu, people ask what is and I have just to reply: "do not touch it, is there but it is not supposed you use it..."...

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm afraid that the dashboard in Orchard is not that flexible.